# jQuery UI draggable makes modals close by click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

My modals close if clicked on certain area twice without drag movement.
I use
https://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/

my website [click here](http://www.HighGamer.com/AOInternational) try the `Pay with Credit/Debit/Gift Card`

you notice that you cannot fill out the form as it will keep closing the modal.

with `draggable();` disabled the modal will never close..

`EDIT:` for a quickfix I did `$( ".tukibox" ).draggable( "destroy" );` which completely defeats the purpose of having draggable widget in the first place and this turns off draggable and the modal stops closing, btw doing `draggable("disable")` still closes the modal.